# Get nearest period date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have 3 period each month.

That is

`6th day - 15th day 
16th day - 25th day
26th day - 5th day (next month)`

I want to round my current date to nearest of previous end period.

The result should be like this :

```
My Date     |  Result Date
2017-06-03  |  2017-05-25
2017-06-08  |  2017-06-05
2017-06-15  |  2017-06-05
2017-06-21  |  2017-06-15
2017-06-24  |  2017-06-15
2017-06-25  |  2017-06-15
2017-06-26  |  2017-06-25
2017-06-28  |  2017-06-25
2017-07-01  |  2017-06-25
```

How can I do this in SQL Server?

I update my requirement. I want to find another way than using `CASE ... WHEN ...` clause. I already solve this problem with that way. :)

I just wonder if there is another way to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE ... WHEN ...` and [DateFromParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) (is avaiable in SQL 2012+) like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (DateValue date)

INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES 
('2017-06-03'),('2017-06-08'),('2017-06-15'),('2017-06-21'),
('2017-06-24'),('2017-06-25'),('2017-06-26'),('2017-06-28'),
('2017-07-01' )


SELECT sd.DateValue AS [My date],
      CASE 
         WHEN datepart(day,sd.DateValue) BETWEEN 6 AND 15 
                THEN DateFromParts(year(sd.DateValue), month(sd.DateValue), 5)
         WHEN datepart(day,sd.DateValue) BETWEEN 16 AND 25
                THEN DateFromParts(year(sd.DateValue), month(sd.DateValue), 15)
         ELSE DateFromParts(year(dateadd(day, - 6, sd.DateValue)), month(dateadd(day, - 6, sd.DateValue)), 25)
      END as [Result Date]
FROM @SampleData sd
```

**Note**: If your date is on `26th day - 5th day` then `dateadd(day, - 6, sd.DateValue)` returns exactly year and month of previous period.

Demo link: http://rextester.com/LTTWC54961

Comment: well, I didn't think that way in the `ELSE` part. That is good! I can add that part to my code. But, Can I solve this problem without `CASE ... WHEN ...` clause tho? It will great to find another way to solve this problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Declare @t table (datevalue date)

insert into @t values ('2017-06-03'),('2017-06-08'),('2017-06-15'),('2017-06-21'),('2017-06-24'),('2017-06-25'),('2017-06-26'),('2017-06-28'),('2017-07-01' )
--2017-06-03  |  2017-05-25
--2017-06-08  |  2017-06-05
--2017-06-15  |  2017-06-05
--2017-06-21  |  2017-06-15
--2017-06-24  |  2017-06-15
--2017-06-25  |  2017-06-15
--2017-06-26  |  2017-06-25
--2017-06-28  |  2017-06-25
--2017-07-01  |  2017-06-25

Select datevalue, cast ( cast( year(datevalue) as varchar(10)) +'/' + cast( month(datevalue) as varchar(10)) + '/26' as date) olddate,
cast ( cast( year(datevalue) as varchar(10)) +'/' + cast( month(datevalue)+1 as varchar(10)) + '/5' as date) newdate,
case 
    when day(datevalue) between 6 and 15 then '5-' + cast( month(datevalue) as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast( year(datevalue) as varchar(10)) 
    when day(datevalue) between 16 and 25 then '15-' + cast( month(datevalue) as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast( year(datevalue) as varchar(10)) 
    when datevalue between cast ( cast( year(datevalue)-1 as varchar(10)) +'/' + cast( month(datevalue) as varchar(10)) + '/26' as date) and cast ( cast( year(datevalue) as varchar(10)) +'/' + cast( month(datevalue) as varchar(10)) + '/5' as date)
    then '25-' + cast( month(datevalue)-1 as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast( year(datevalue) as varchar(10)) 
    else  '25-' + cast( month(datevalue) as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast( year(datevalue) as varchar(10)) 
end
from @t
```

Comment: This isn't the requirement.  `6th - 15th day` is the first range, not 1-15.

Comment: Agreed - note that for the very first sample row, `2017-06-03` should produce `2017-05-25`. I don't think you code does.

Comment: thanks Ajay for your answer :). But actually I already have the answer that using `CASE ... WHEN ...` clause. I just wonder if I can simplify the trick in the fancy way. I'm sorry I didn't tell my requirement clearly.

Comment: please elaborate that we help you. no issue id you already solved.

Comment: My code have a huge line number. This `Result Date` will be used in some `CASE ... WHEN ...` also. So it will be great if I can simplify query to get this Result Date.

Comment: there is no other option as you need to manipulate resultdate based on condition for each row. you can store your temporary result in cte or temporary table to understand more, but no other way. by the way huge line number what effect the case when statement. are you stuck some where?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
declare @t table (MyDate date,Expected date)
insert into @t(MyDate,Expected) values
('20170603','20170525'),
('20170608','20170605'),
('20170615','20170605'),
('20170621','20170615'),
('20170624','20170615'),
('20170625','20170615'),
('20170626','20170625'),
('20170628','20170625'),
('20170701','20170625')

select
    t.*,
    CASE
        WHEN Day25 < MyDate THEN Day25
        WHEN Day15 < MyDate THEN Day15
        WHEN Day05 < MyDate THEN Day05
        ELSE
            DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',MyDate),'20001225')
    END as Actual,
    u.*
from
    @t t
        cross apply
    (
        select
            DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',t.MyDate),'20010105') as Day05,
            DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',t.MyDate),'20010115') as Day15,
            DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',t.MyDate),'20010125') as Day25
    ) u
```

Basically, for each date we compute the possible cutoff dates within the same month and then pick the latest such one that is before the "My" date.

If none of those apply then we compute the 25th of the previous month instead

Result:

```
MyDate     Expected   Actual                  Day05                   Day15                   Day25
---------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2017-06-03 2017-05-25 2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-06-08 2017-06-05 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-06-15 2017-06-05 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-06-21 2017-06-15 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-06-24 2017-06-15 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-06-25 2017-06-15 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-06-26 2017-06-25 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-06-28 2017-06-25 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-15 00:00:00.000 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
2017-07-01 2017-06-25 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000 2017-07-05 00:00:00.000 2017-07-15 00:00:00.000 2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
```

(I just included the `u` columns in this result so you can see how they've been worked out)

The constant dates used within the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` expressions are somewhat arbitrary - they're just picked such that they have the particular relationships between them such that we want to apply that same relationship to `MyDate`.

If `MyDate` is a `datetime` or `datetime2` with a time component, then  you might also want to cast it to `date` or otherwise remove the time component before using it in the comparisons, depending on your exact requirement.